# Refresh jquery object after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a lucky spin script that need to get random number from database and let it spin to the number.

The problem is, after document.ready, I cant assign any value to the object option again.

```
<input type="button" value="test" id="playBtn" onclick="getluckynumber();"/>
    <input type="button" id="fire" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="luck" value=""/>

function getluckynumber(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"ajax.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{event_id:'<?=$event_id ?>'},
            })
                    .done(function(data){
                        $("#luck").val(data);
                        $("#fire").trigger("click"); 
                    });
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.slot').jSlots({
                spinner:'#fire',
                endNumbers:$("#luck").val(),
            });
        });
```

How to make the "endNumbers" to take new value?

UPDATE:
https://jsfiddle.net/asaxpse3/1/

UPDATE:
The final working code

```
var getNewNumber=function(spinner){
        $.ajax({
            url:"ajax.php",
            method:"POST",
            async:false,
            data:{event_id:'23'},
        })
                .done(function(data){
                    if(data){
                        spinner.options.endNumbers=JSON.parse(data);
                        //console.log(data);
                    }
                });
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.slot').jSlots({
            spinner:'#playBtn',
            onStart:getNewNumber
        });
    });
```

Thanks to skobaljic.

Comment: you want to modify the slots end number when the slots plugin is already triggered?

Comment: It is a modified experimental plugin, you can find it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d3fZV/).

Comment: @madalinivascu yes, is it possible?

Comment: @skobaljic i get the script from there too, but i need some extra modification to get target number from database

Comment: hard to say, you will need to modify the script or write a completely new one

Comment: @poiseberry I am telling people where you found the script, so they can help you. I also tried to fix it, but I saw you had to change it (as madalin ivascu said so), or to re-create the slot after ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the function on `onStart` option, but you have to change the plugin code and provide the spinner instance as parameter:

```
if ($.isFunction(base.options.onStart)) {
    base.options.onStart( base );
}
```

Than you should define the random number function generator, for example:

```
var getNewNumber = function( spinner ) {
    /* Some SYNC!! ajax stuff, than when done: */
    //the returned data is a array, eg [1,3,4]
    //for the spinner to stop at 134
    spinner.options.endNumbers = [1, 3, 4];
};
```

And at the end, bind the generator function to plugin's `onStart` option:

```
$('.slot').jSlots({
    spinner: '#playBtn',
    endNumbers: [],
    onStart: getNewNumber
});
```

Please note: The AJAX must be sync, use param `async: false`.

**[Complete code here](https://jsfiddle.net/asaxpse3/3/)**

Comment: Where should I put this `if ($.isFunction(base.options.onStart)) {
    base.options.onStart( base );
}` ? I couldn't found in your complete code, thanks

Comment: You can copy the code into text editor and find it, or you can just copy the plugin code and use it.